# Line break not working in template literal

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a template literal but whenever I'm adding a new line, its not recognising it.

```
<div className='tipbox'><HiOutlineLightBulb style={{marginRight:"10px"}}/>{
         
         `THIS IS MY FIRST LINE.

         THIS IS MY SECOND LINE

         THIS IS MY THIRD LINE
         
          `
         
         }</div> }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a "\n" for new line

Comment: Your `div` needs to be styled with `whitespace: pre;`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space